# How to get part of string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, text

I have an array with one element

```
ClickMeArray[0] = "ClickMe=a-6,a-7,a-8,a-9,"
```

I want variable to return elements after `ClickMe=` from `ClickMeArray`.

Output should be `a-6,a-7,a-8,a-9,`.

Comment: If the "ClickMe=" is always the same you can use `.substr(8)` in order to offset the first chars.

Comment: is it always the same string or can it be other words followed by `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClickMeArray[0].split('ClickMe=')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var val = "ClickMe=a-6,a-7,a-8,a-9,"; 
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("=") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do this work. One way is using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). You can replace `ClickMe=` with empty to getting another part of string.

```js
var ClickMeArray = "ClickMe=a-6,a-7,a-8,a-9,";
console.log(ClickMeArray.replace('ClickMe=',''));
```